# Seeking VRP solver in pgRouting 2?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

after looking at older posts and googling for a while i guess there is not vrp solver (multiple trucks).

there was DARP in pgr1.x but i can't see it in 2.x.

i found a lot of information on https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/VRP-Algorithms

Comment: Few years ago I had the same question and ended up having an external code of my own simulating this. Maybe OpenTripPlanner, OSRM or GoFleet can help you here.

Comment: bad news. well. I spoke few developers and i am told that There has been a new algorithm developed just recently and will hopefully be released soon as an addition to the pgRouting library. It's originally developed for garbage collection, so it can handle capacity constraints as well as dump locations. But it also supports a long-requested feature: multiple depot sites.